# git pull request on visualstudio online

Tags: git, azure-devops

I like to do code reviews using git pull requests in visual studio online. Is there any way to do this without cloning a second repo in visual studio online? Ideally I want visual studio online to use our existing git repo and import it rather clone it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "your existing git repo"?  Is this some repository stored in another provider?  (GitHub, Bitbucket, a local share?)  If so, what do you mean "import" that is somehow different than "clone"?

Comment: we have our own git server, we clone that repository into our local environment. we dont have a github account either. ideally i would like to just use git pull requests in visualstudio online

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Git pull requests in VSO your repository needs to the stored in VSO. There is no way around this.

Pull requests are also available in TFS 2013.4. If you were to install TFS locally and use TFS as your Git server rather than your current solution, you can leverage the capability.